# Http post request in angular 2 to ReST API

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to implement get and post request in angular 2 with the Rest API created .

I am able to successfully implement the get request and fetch data from my API.

But i am unable to make a post request.

### Below shown is my Rest microservice code

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/checkUsers")
public String checkLogin() throws JsonProcessingException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Users> useObj = (List<Users>) userRepo.findAll();
    return(mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj));
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkByCredential", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkLoginByName(@RequestBody Users user) throws Exception{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Users useObj1 = 
userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.username,user.password);
    return(mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj1));
}
```

### Below shown is my angular 2 code snippets

### app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';


@NgModule({

  declarations  : [AppComponent ],
  imports       : [BrowserModule,HttpModule,FormsModule ],
  providers     : [BasicService],
  bootstrap     : [LoginpostComponent]

})

export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BasicService } from './basic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
            <div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto;"> 
             <table *ngFor= " let item of data">
                 <tr><td>Username</td><td>{{ item.username }}</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>Password</td><td>{{ item.password }}</td></tr>
             </table>
            </div>`

})
export class AppComponent {
  title :string;
  data:any;

  constructor(private MyService: BasicService){
        this.title="Angular Service";

        this.MyService.GetUsers()
        .subscribe(users => {this.data = users });
  }
}
```

### basic.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class BasicService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

    GetUsers(){
            return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/checkUsers')
            .map(result => result.json());
    }


}
```

can anybody please guide how to implement the post request with my ReSTAPI ,so that when i submit my form data it should authenticate the credentials from  my API

Answer (score 1):

A POST call in Angular 2+ can be made in a similar fashion to the `GetUsers()` call you already have:

```js
checkByCredential(username: string, password: string) {
  const user = { username: username, password: password };
  return this.http
    .post('http://localhost:8080/checkByCredential', user) // Just add the second argument
    .map(result => result.json());
}
```

The `user` object should have the same structure as the `Users` class (the `@RequestBody` parameter in your controller). You could even create a TypeScript interface for it.

Additionally, you don't need to the the `mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj)`, Spring boot does that for you, so you could refactor your Java code to:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping("/checkUsers")
public List<Users> checkLogin() throws JsonProcessingException {
    return (List<Users>) userRepo.findAll();
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkByCredential", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Users checkLoginByName(@RequestBody Users user) throws Exception{
    return userRepo.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.username,user.password);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply iwill try to implement this

Comment: i added it in my service and subscribed in my component but i am getting the following error while compilation

Comment: ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(25,6): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.

Comment: this.MyService.checkByCredential()
      .subscribe(users => {this.data = users });

Comment: this.MyService.checkByCredential()
      .subscribe(users => {this.data = users });

Comment: please clarify my doubt

Comment: now i am getting this error in my console "AppComponent.html:29 ERROR TypeError: _co.checkByCredential is not a function"

Comment: but i have added that function in my service below the GetUsers function in my basis.service.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159459/discussion-between-heena-and-g00glen00b).